# Adding a click even to a Leaflet Marker

Tags: javascript, onclick, leaflet

I am using Leaflet and I have several markers on the map. I am trying to trigger a click event so that when I click on one of the markers it will scroll to a `div` down the page

For example, the marker is created like this:

```
var marker = L.marker([ 51.5, -0.09 ]).addTo(map);
```

Can I add a click event to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind event on your marker when you initialize it. When the click is fired you just redirect to the dom element you want :

```js
var marker = L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map).on('mouseover', () => {
    document.location.href = "#id_of_div";
});
```